# MapDispatchToProps include all actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When using `import * as MyActions from 'not/important'`

Is it possible to then send all of `MyActions` to component props?

```
connect(mapStateToProps, { MyActions})(MyClass)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
connect(mapStateToProps, MyActions)(MyClass)
```

Or if you want to include more actions from other places, you can use the spread operator `...`:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, { action1, action2, ...MyActions })(MyClass)
```